# How to create "dynamic" stored proc without using dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, snapshot

I have an existing SP.
I want to start using database snapshots in some cases.
Users can save a snapshot at any time.
If they do, the SP should use it.
Otherwise, use the primary database.

I want to adapt the SPs to handle this, by making the database/table names dynamic instead of hard-coded in the SP.

I can imagine something like this working, with fully qualified table names, but it gives the error 'Must declare the table variable "@db1"':

```
declare @table1 varchar(25);
set @table1 = Snapshot.schema.tablename;
select * from @table1;
```

This gives "Incorrect syntax near '@db'."

```
declare @db varchar(25);
set @db = "Snapshot";
use @db;
```

This sorta works, but the "use" is only in effect during the execute. By the time the 'select' is executed, you are back to using the original database.

```
declare @db varchar(25);
set @db = 'use Snapshot';
EXECUTE(@db);
select * from Schema.Tablename;
```

I know I could generate the entire SP on the fly, but that seems guaranteed to get rejected by the DBAs. I'd rather a less radical solution.

Any better ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462410/how-to-run-the-same-query-on-all-the-databases-on-an-instance

Comment: AFAIK, the `USE` statement can't take variables. it can only be hard coded.