# Perform same SQL query on multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to adapt an SQL query to check the value present in a certain field that is present in every database on my server.

There are 100 individual databases, and I would like to check a specific record of each one.

The answer is probably to use a command like the one below, but I'm having difficulty adapting it.

```
EXECUTE sp_MSForEachDB 
    'USE ?; SELECT DB_NAME()AS DBName, 
    COUNT(1)AS [Count] FROM CUSTOMERS'
```

I have had greater success with the link below;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18462734/3461845

I need to be able to perform this query:

```
SELECT [SettingName],[SettingValue]  FROM [HostSettings] Where [SettingName] = 'SMTPServer'
```

And also pull back the name of the database for each row that is returned;

```
DBName | SettingName | SettingValue

Database1 | SMTPServer | smtp.gmail.com

Database2 | SMTPServer | smtp.gmail.com

Database3 | SMTPServer | smtp.yahoo.com
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
([DbName] SYSNAME,
[SettingName] VARCHAR(255),
[SettingValue] VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO
@T
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB
'SELECT
    ''?'',
    [SettingName],
    [SettingValue]
FROM
    [?]..[HostSettings]
WHERE
    [SettingName] = ''SMTPServer''';

SELECT * FROM @T;
```

Comment: Thank you for replying,
I'm afraid I get the following error
Incorrect syntax near '-'.
I've had a google, and it might be to do with whitespace, but I've tried stripping out what I can and it's still not working.

Comment: I think this is because my table names have hyphens in them... Just trying to work this out now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Registered Servers in SSMS.  To run the same query on all databases.

1. In SSMS, go to **View**
2. Then **Registered Servers**
3. Right Click on **Local Server Group** then **New Server Group**
4. Type any name for the Group
5. Then the the Group name you created, right click and **New Server Registration**
6. And Server name **Localhost** (for example)
7. Then Right Click on **Localhost** and **New Query**.  That will run all the same query on all databases

Comment: I have tried this, and it doesn't work for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore below. Try this.

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100)= 'SMTPServer'
SET @sql = 'EXECUTE sp_MSForEachDB 
    ''USE ?; SELECT DB_NAME()AS DBName, 
        SettingName,
        SettingValue
    FROM HostSettings
    WHERE SettingName =''' + '''' + @string +'''''' + ''''

EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @userdb_list table (name varchar(4000) not null);
-- fill the db list with custom subset
insert into @userdb_list
select name from sys.databases --can add where condition to filter db names

declare
@curr_userdb varchar(300),
@db_placeholder varchar(300),
@final_db_exec_query varchar(max),
@query varchar(max);
set @query = '' --  <add ur query here> 

set @db_placeholder = 'use {db}'; 
set @curr_userdb = (select min(name) from @userdb_list);

while @curr_userdb is not null
begin
set @final_db_exec_query = replace(@db_placeholder, '{db}', @curr_userdb +  '  ' + @query);
exec (@final_db_exec_query);
--print @final_db_exec_query
set @curr_userdb = (select min(name) from @userdb_list where name > @curr_userdb);
end
GO
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).