# How to get the objects for specific database?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a procedure which takes as an argument database name and I need using that database name to get all objects refer to it including tables,views,triggers which dictionary would be helpful to find those information ?

NOTE :I Tryed to use **`SELECT * FROM sys.obj`** but that gives me the whole objects in all databases .
how can i restrict them to specifc database

Comment: You will have to use dynamic sql. And you will need to include the database name as part of your dynamic sql. "Select * from " + @DBName + ".sys.objects..."

Comment: When modified this answer should get you going: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18462734/2095534

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run the same statement which you mentioned in **NOTE** . Then I am getting only the Objects which I was connected to. So simply add `USE`  to get connected to particular db. And hit the `sys.objects` table.

So your SP will be like

```
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_GETALLOBJ
(
@DB_NAME VARCHAR(20)
)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @QRY VARCHAR(MAX);

    SELECT @QRY = '
    USE ' +@DB_NAME+'

    SELECT * FROM SYS.objects WHERE [TYPE] NOT IN (''SQ'',''S'',''IT'')'
    
    EXEC (@QRY)
    
END
GO
```

I have removed rows which are of Type `SQ,S,IT` with `NOT IN`. Because you might not need them.

Please find the list of types with Description.

> TR --TRIGGER
>
> SQ --SERVICE_QUEUE
>
> FN --SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION
>
> S  --SYSTEM_TABLE
>
> D  --DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT
>
> IT --INTERNAL_TABLE
>
> F  --FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT
>
> PK --PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT
>
> P  --SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE
>
> U  --USER_TABLE
>
> TF --SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION
>
> UQ --UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT
>
> V  --VIEW