# How to search a table in all databases where column value is the given text

Tags: sql-server

I'm able to query all the databases via [How to run the same query on all the databases on an instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462410/how-to-run-the-same-query-on-all-the-databases-on-an-instance) but not sure how to run the query by matching a specific column and value.

example, assume column name is code. query + code='THBN'

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EXECUTE sp_MSForEachDB 
'USE ?; 
SELECT * from table where code=''tbhn''';
```

you could also ignore system databases like below

```
EXECUTE sp_MSForEachDB 
'if db_id()>4
begin
SELECT * from table where code=''tbhn''
end';
```